# Installing MonetDB ODBC on windows 10 x64

Tags: monetdb, monetdblite

The [installation page](https://www.monetdb.org/downloads/Windows/) does not mention Windows 10. Is it possible to download MonetDB ODBC for that OS? If so, where can I find the steps to do so.

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1):

The MonthYear combinations are MonetDB versions, the latest being Mar2018-SP1. You will find the 64-Bit ODBC installer here: https://www.monetdb.org/downloads/Windows/Mar2018-SP1/MonetDB-ODBC-Installer-x86_64-20180531.msi

Comment: Is there a test to determine if it's installed correctly if I'm using MonetDBLite? I'm trying to replicate [this](https://notstatschat.rbind.io/2018/09/27/how-to-write-a-racist-ai-in-r-without-really-trying/), but keep getting weird errors, and googling isn't helpful!

Comment: You need to only install the MonetDBLite R package, not MonetDB itself to replicate the script you linked to. So `install.packages("MonetDBLite")` should be enough.

Comment: Thank you. I will uninstall the downloaded version.